# Why my react state became not-immutable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

As I remember in past I could not update react-state manualy.
Now, I don't know why, I can do it.

My case:
[image]

and the property is changed here!It works! Why?

[image]

P.s: I use react16.02

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from setting `this.state` manually - there's just no guarantee that React won't throw the changes away/overwrite them. In other words, you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: You should keep states and props immutable by yourself. React doesn't do it, just requires that. 61st line, you just assign this.state.newOptions link to the `newOptions` variable, and after that you change it, so it's predictable that your `state` changes =)

Comment: It's important to note that you treat it as immutable, like @AndrewParamoshkin says, because you're supposed to have React do the heavy lifting for DOM renders. Always use `this.setState` to change `this.state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the state does mutate in react. and u should be very careful that u don't override it like that or you will encounter unexpected result. it is always best to copy your state into another object, then change its properties as u like and after you are done use set state to set set your object state as copied object.
you can use Object.Assign or spread operator for this. spread operator is easier when you are using Arrays.

```
this.state = {
  myObj : {propA: "A" , propB: "B"};
}
```

then at some point you want to change it

```
let myObj = this.state.myObj;
let copyMyObj = {...myObj};
copyMyObj.propA = "C";
this.setState({
myObj: copyMyObj
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript objects are mutable.

For example if

```
var a = {"something": 1}
```

and if you assign it to another variable `b` and if you change its value, the value of object `a` is also changed

```
var b = a;
b.something = 2;
console.log(b);
console.log(a);

//output {"something": 2}
```

both will print {"something": 2}. The value in a is also changed.

Similarly in your code you are directly assigning the state value in line number `61` and mutating it in line number `62`.

So better way is to use

```
let newOptions = {...this.state.newOptions };
```

or

```
let newOptions = Object.assign({},this.state.newOptions}
```

This will create new object.

Answer (score 2):

React state is mutable, so you can update react state directly. But it is recommended not to mutate react state due to multiple reasons. One of the reasons is, if you do `this.state.count = 3`, react DOM will behave in an unpredictable manner such as overwriting data and not re-rendering. Performance tuning is another reason.

React on calling `setState()` will call the `render` method in some near future which will cause the DOM to be updated with new values.